# Using array returned by String.split

Tags: javascript

```
data = 'numbersXXXtext';
```

or

```
data = 'XXXtext';


var get = data.split('XXX');
var sum = get[1];
```

I would like get always "text". If `data` equals `numbersXXXtext`, the code works fine, but if `data` is `XXXtext` then `get[1]` is undefinded.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be get[0] since it is the first, and only, item in the array?

Comment: I've posted an answer, and @Matt has proposed a neater alternative in a comment, but in which browser do you get `undefined`? I tried in Chrome and IE and `"XXXtest".split("XXX")[1]` returns `"test"`

Comment: Also, never name a variable `get`. `get` has become sort of a keyword.

Comment: Just looked it up in ECMA Script definition (ECMA-262, June 2011). I'm pretty sure that it should return an array with 2 elements: "" and "text". It certainly does in Java, and I would be very surprised if this isn't the same in most programming environments.

Comment: @Grillz no, normally it splits it into parts between the separator, *even if those parts are zero characters in size*, see my comment before this one

Comment: [@owlstead](http://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/owlstead) is correct

Comment: Mark, could you please add the runtime information (e.g. browser + version & platform) to the quesion for future reference, this seems to be an implementation mistake in the runtime

Comment: This sounds to me like a JavaScript bug in MS IE7 and WSScript (or whatever) related to regexps, but you seem to be using a string, not a regexp. Have you rewritten before posting?

Comment: i had other bug in my code - so i had these error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sum = get.length > 1 ? get[1] : get[0]
```

Comment: `get[get.length -1]` would be a (better?) alternative.

Answer (score 6):

If there is only one occurrence of `XXX` in the string, the bit you want will always be the last item in the array returned by `split`. You can use `pop` to get the last item of an array:

```
var a = "numbersXXXtext";
var b = "XXXtext";

console.log(a.split('XXX').pop()); // "text"
console.log(b.split('XXX').pop()); // "text"
```

Comment: I guess it's important to note here that this will **remove** the last element from the array; not just retrieve it.

Comment: Indeed, though it's immaterial in my answer because the array returned from `split` is never stored. You're right, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, i just tried your code, and it's working. (http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/)
Are you sure you are not missing something?

```
    data = 'numbersXXXtext';
   //data = 'XXXtext';
    var get = data.split('XXX');

    document.write(get[1]);
    document.write("</br>");
    document.write(get);
    document.write("</br>");
```

I didn't get undefined in neither of your strings

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using substring:

```
var data = 'numbersXXXtext';
var value = data.substring(data.indexOf('XXX') + 'XXX'.length);
```